# When does #: give more desirable behavior than #.^:_1

Tags: j

If you give the inverse of Base (`#.^:_1`) a list as the left argument, it will produce the same result as Antibase (`#:`):

```
   24 60 (#.^:_1) 123456
17 36
   24 60 (#:) 123456
17 36
```

If you give Antibase (`#:`) a single left argument, it duplicates the Residue (`|`), rather than the inverse of Base (`#.^:_1`):

```
   8 #: 1234
2
   8 | 1234
2
   8 (#.^:_1) 1234
2 3 2 2
```

Under what circumstances would the behavior of Antibase be superior to an inverted Base? And why wouldn't you just use Residue in those places? I feel like I must be missing something obvious about the utility of Antibase's behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with: *the J Dictionary defines `#.^:_1` to be equivalent to `#:`*, so it shouldn't be surprising that they're (mostly) interchangeable. In particular, [the Vocabulary page for `#:` says](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d402.htm) :

> r&#: is inverse to r&#."

And this theoretical equivalence is also supported in practice.  If you ask the implementation of J for the *its* definition of `#.^:_1`, using the super-cool adverb `b.`, you'll get:

```
   24 60 60&#. b._1
24 60 60&#:
```

Here, we can see that all `#.^:_1` is doing is deferring to `#:`. They're defined to be equivalent, and now we can see `#.^:_1` -- *at least in the case of a non-scalar LHA¹* -- is simply passing its arguments through to `#:`.

So how do we explain the discrepancy you observed? Well it turns out that, even in the pure halls of J, theory differs from practice.  There is an inconsistency between dyads `#:` and `#.^:_1` and, at least in the case of scalar left arguments, the behavior of the latter is superior to the former.

I would (and [have](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/System/Interpreter/Bugs06#definition_of_dyad_.23%3a_incomplete)) argue that this discrepancy is a bug: the Dictionary, quoted above, states the two dyads are equivalent, but that assertion is *wrong* when `0-:#$r` (i.e. `r` is a scalar). Take `r=.2` for example: `(r&#: -: r&#.^:_1) 1 2 3` does not hold. That is, if the Dictionary's assertion (quoted above) is true, that statement should return `1` (true), but it actually returns `0` (false).

But, as you pointed out, it is a *useful* bug.  Which is to say: I'd prefer the definition of `#:` were changed to match `#.^:_1`, rather than vice-versa.  But that's the *only* time `#.^:_1` is more convenient than `#:`. In all other cases, they're equivalent, and because `#:` is a primitive and `#.^:_1` is compound phrase with a trailing `_1`, the former is much more convenient.

For example, when your right-hand argument is a numeric literal, it's easy to get that inadvertently attached to the `_1` in `#.^:_1`, as in `2 2 2 2 #.^:_1   15 7 4 5`, which will raise an error (because `_1 15 7 4 5` is lexed as a single word, and therefore taken, as a whole, to be the argument to `^:`). There are ways to address this, but none of them are as convenient or simple as using `#:`.

You could make a counterargument that in most cases, the LHA will be a scalar. That's an empirical argument, which will vary from codebase to codebase, but I personally see a lot of cases like `24 60 60 #: ...`, where I'm trying to break up timestamps into duration buckets (hours, minutes, seconds), or `(8#2)#: ...`, where I'm trying explode bytes into *exactly* 8-bit vectors (contrasted to, e.g., `8 #.^:_1 ...`, which will break bytes into as many bits as it takes, whether that's 8 or 3 or 17¹).  And I'd further argue that in the J community, these are both commonly-used and instantly-recognizable idioms, so the use of `#:` assists with clarity and team communication.

But, bugs notwithstanding, ultimately `#:` and `#.^:_1` are *defined to be equivalent*, so which one you use is really a matter of taste. (Then why define `#.^:_1` at all, you ask? Well, that's a [whole 'nother story](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Under).)

---

¹ PS:  Wanna see something cool?  How does `#.^:_1` achieve its magic for scalar LHAs?  Let's just ask J!

```
   2&#. b._1
($&2@>:@(2&(<.@^.))@(1&>.)@(>./)@:|@, #: ]) :.(2&#.)
```

First off, notice the (by now) completely unsurprising use of `#:`. All `#.^:_1` is doing is calculating the appropriate LHA for `#:`.

Second, the phrase `$&2@>:@(2&(<.@^.))@(1&>.)@(>./)@:|@,` shows you how J calculates the number of digits required to represent (the maximum value of) the y in the base (or radix) x.  And it's a useful phrase unto itself, so much so that I keep a version of it around in my personal utility library:

```
   ndr =: 10&$: :(>:@<.@^. (1 >. >./@:|@,))
   ndr 1 10 100 101             NB. Number Digits Required in [default] base 10
3
   16 ndr 1 10 100 101          NB. Number Digits Required in hexadecimal
2
```

Comment: Absolutely excellent information. I think, bottom line, you're saying that it would be better if `#:` behaved like `#.^:_1`, and that there is not a situation in which its behavior is superior.

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is that from a user perspective, you'd always want to use `#:` (because it's shorter to write, easier to read, and doesn't have the `_1` issue), but at the moment you're forced to use `#.^_1` when `x` is scalar, because `#:` has a bug in that case (arguably). 

In other words, when `x` is not scalar, the verbs behave the same, but `#:`'s lexibility does make it superior for reading/writing.

Comment: I understand why you might use `#:` instead of `#.^:_1` in practice, but I asked about the desirability of the behavior. If I were to insist on using English words instead of symbols, I presume there is no reason to go with `Antibase =: #:` over `Antibase =: #.^:_1`, correct?

Comment: Correct. The behavior of both is the same, except where `x` is scalar, in which case the behavior (as opposed to spelling) of `#.^:_1` is preferable. In quantitative terms, for scalar `x`, it's easier to express `#:` in terms of `#.^:_1` than vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not an overwhelmingly compelling application but,

```
 (4 # 256) #: 8234092340238420938420394820394820349820349820349x
```

is 10x faster than

```
 256 #. inv (2^32x) | 8234092340238420938420394820394820349820349820349x
```